# Strategies for dealing with horribly out of date software in the Ubuntu repos

Tags: apt

It's been about 5 years since I've used an Ubuntu based distro as my daily driver and now I'm starting remember some of the reasons why I ditched it for Arch Linux; horribly out of date software packages in the Ubuntu repositories being one.

For example I just went to install Ansible today via apt-get and it was version 1.54...whaaaaat....

Checking the Ansible docs I can add the ppa:ansible/ansible repo, but is the only solution to manually add a zillion custom ppa's everytime I want to get current software?

Does anyone know of a tool that will automatically check for a current ppa for an application before it installs some ancient release found in the stock Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Just be aware, that there currently is a maximum number of ppas you can add, and with just 40 ppas that number is quite low.

Comment: I recently learned that the long neglected Ubuntu Software Center has been replaced with Gnome Software in the 16.04 LTS release, maybe that will help the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this tool could help you : [Y-PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/y-ppa-manager-updated-with-important.html)

However, you'll have first to search with this tool by yourself.

Regards,

Nikos